# How to successfully reference another table before insert with a trigger

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create a trigger to validate if a new entry in the table `registraties` (registrations) contains a valid MNR (employee number) but I'm getting stuck on the part where I'm referencing the table `medewerkers` (employees).

Could someone help me out?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_MNRcontrole

BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON registraties

DECLARE 
MNR_medewerkers number (SELECT MNR FROM MEDEWERKERS);

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 

IF :new.MNR <> MNR_medewerkers
THEN raise_application_error(-20111, 'Medewerker niet herkend!');

END IF;
END;
```

Error message received is 
`ORA-24344: success with compilation error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PL/SQL assignment operator is `:=`, or `select x into y from z` to populate from a SQL query.

`FOR EACH ROW` is part of the trigger spec, not the PL/SQL code.

If `:new.mnr` is not present in the parent table, you will get a `no_data_found` exception, not a mismatched variable.

It's good practice for error messages to include details of what failed.

In programming, we use indentation to indicate code structure.

A fixed version would be something like:

```
create or replace trigger trg_mnrcontrole
    before insert or update on registraties
    for each row
declare
    mnr_medewerkers medewerkers.mnr%type;
begin
    select mw.mnr into mnr_medewerkers
    from   medewerkers mw
    where  mw.mnr = :new.mnr;

exception  
    when no_data_found then
        raise_application_error(-20111, 'Medewerker '||:new.mnr||' niet herkend!');
end;
```

However, we can implement this kind of check better using a [foreign key constraint](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/constraint.html), for example:

```
alter table registraties add constraint registraties_mw_fk
foreign key (mnr) references medewerkers.mnr;
```

Comment: Thank you! I've added the error code and I'm actually not sure how to indent, tried `TAB` but it didn't seem to work. Just found a site which says it can be changed in settings so I'll try that out in a bit. I think your solution should work, I'm not used to the `SELECT INTO` statements. I'm still getting familiar with the possibilities. Thanks so much for your explanation.

Comment: A trigger is not the best way to solve it - foreign key constraints exist for this purpose. Have a look at that instead

Comment: I don't know what editor you're using, but I find 4 spaces does the job :)

Answer (score 0):

> MNR_medewerkers number (SELECT MNR FROM MEDEWERKERS);

will always fail because its not a NUMBER, unless your table happens to only have one single entry and even then I am not sure PLSQL will allow it to pass.

The more standard case for this would be to first declare the number, then in the codeblock you do a SELECT INTO along with a WHERE clause where you make sure to only pick one specific row from the table. Then you can compare that number with the new one.

If however you are not trying to compare to one specific row, but are instead checking if the entry exists in that table.

```
BEGIN
  SELECT 1
    INTO m_variable
    FROM table
   WHERE MNR = :new.MNR;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    m_variable = 1;
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    m_variable = 0;
END;
```

Declare the m_variable beforehand, and then check if its 0 then report the error.

The too_many_rows is in case there is more than one row in the table with this MNR, and the OTHERS is there for the NO_DATA_FOUND, but I use OTHERS to handle everything else that could happen but probably wont.

Btw this is a code block to be included within the main code block, so between your BEGIN and IF, then just change the IF to check if the variable is 0.

Comment: I feel like your answer should work, however I'm not able to get it to work. To clarify, the MNR is a PK in `medewerkers` and I want to check if, when trying to register (insert a row into the table `registraties`), the employee (MNR) is already known. If not, to show the error.